# I didn't understand this error : TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable of my program

Tags: python, function, numpy

I tried to make a wordcloud of wikipedia page.
So that I write code and this code will give an error but I didn't understand the error.

I put mask.png in a current working directory but still, it gives an error.

```
import wikipedia
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

currdir=os.path.dirname(__file__)

def get_wiki(query):
   title=wikipedia.search(query)[0]
   page=wikipedia.page(title)
   return page.content
```

Second line of this function(createword) will create a function error.

```
def createwordcloud(text):
   mask=np.array(Image.open(os.path.join[currdir,"masks.png"]))
   stopwords=set(STOPWORDS)
   wc=WordCloud(background_color="white",
             mask=mask,
             max_words=100,
             stopwords=STOPWORDS)
   wc.generate(text)
   wc.to_file(os.path.join(currdir,"wc.png"))


createwordcloud(get_wiki("Tata Motors"))
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `join[...]`? Did you mean to use `()` instead of square braces? `join` is presumably a function.

Comment: `os.path.join[currdir,"masks.png"]` should be `os.path.join(currdir,"masks.png")`.  `[...]` denotes a subscription of the object, where as `(...)` calls the object.  Since `join` is a function and not subscriptable, you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your line:

```
mask=np.array(Image.open(os.path.join[currdir,"masks.png"]))
```

should be:

```
mask=np.array(Image.open(os.path.join(currdir,"masks.png")))
```

`os.path.join` is a function and its arguments must be passed with `()`. Using `[]` implies you are subscripting it. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).